# angular ui bootstrap typeahead - add class ,when appended to body

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, object-reference, angular-ui-typeahead

I am using angular bootstrap typeahead in my project. And there are several instances of it being used.

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead

Couple of them are directly appended to body using option "typeahead-append-to-body", so for one instance, I need to customize the presentation, i.e. may be add a css class to that particular instance only i.e. to the ul, dropdown-menu which it creates. But am not able to do that, as I couldnt find any way. Had it been appended to the input element's parents, it would have been easy, but when appended to body, it seems difficult.

```
<input type="text" typeahead-append-to-body="true" typeahead="state as state.name for state in statesWithFlags | filter:{name:$viewValue}" typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html">
```

I dont want to directly target using body > .dropdown-menu as it would affect other instances as well.

Comment: Can you add a class custom for this code to reference ... ie. `class="u-targetting-typeahead"`?

Comment: But how do I add that, the dropdown list is generated on the fly with only class ".dropdown-menu" attached to it.

Comment: IF you add the class to the input, then it can be used to reference the dropdown ... therefore, it becomes `.u-targetting-typeahead > .dropdown-menu`

Comment: Nope he can't as it is appended to the <body> element and therefore can't be targeted with that piece of CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally realized, I could simply use css attribute selector targetting the html template I am using.

With help of attibute "typeahead-template-url = 'mysearchdropdownpage.html' " which is mentioned in input typeahead, I wrote the following in css.

HTML

```
<input type="search" typeahead="searchItem for searchItem in searchTypeAhead" typeahead-template-url = 'mysearchdropdownpage.html' />
```

CSS

```
ul.dropdown-menu[template-url='mysearchdropdownpage.html']
```

and its works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can add a class to the `input` tag that will allow a more accurate reference to the dropdown menu ...

```
<input class="u-targetting-typeahead" ...>
```

... then, in the css file ...

```
.u-targetting-typeahead > .dropdown-menu
```

... which then references **just** that input's dropdown menu.

The dropdown menu is created on the fly, but the input is created in HTML and that should be the element you use to create the reference point when you want to be this specific.

**ADJUSTMENT**

Looking at ...

**typeahead-append-to-body** (Defaults: false) : Should the typeahead popup be appended to $body instead of the parent element?

If you set this to `false`, the method above would work.  I can't see any other reasonable alternatives.

Comment: I got your point, but as I said, the dropdown-menu is directly appended to the body, not next to input or a child of input.  The input is deep inside the body somewhere and the dropdown-menu is direct descendant of body.

Comment: I made an adjustment to the answer (sorry, I missed the append-to-body code).

Comment: Yeah, I understand, but in my case, I need it to append to body only.